How can I export the registry settings for "shell"/UI settings & behavior?
I'm backing up a Windows profile of mine, for use on a new machine (possibly with a newer Windows version).
Now, I don't want to back up my entirey registry hive, both since I'm worried about compatibility reasons and because I don't want to carry forward any state which may be causing problems in my existing profile. I basically only want to export the UI/Shell behavior settings, such as:

Toolbar visibility and position,
Whether or not hidden or system files are hidden in Explorer
Having gotten rid of the Cortana and search boxes on my Taskbar
Login/lock screen background image path

these sorts of things. I realize this is a vague definition, but - can I characterize the branches of the registry which contain all / almost all of these, and not much or nothing else? If not, is there some other way to back up these settings rather than some full-blown profile backup?
PS - In case it matters, it's a Windows 10 machine.
